# Unconfirmed Transactions

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

Two of my transactions are still unconfirmed after more than 24 hours. The estimated confirmation times at blockchain.info are not accurate.  5 hours ago the estimate was 3 hours now it's saying 22 hours....etc. I know it's because I made the mistake of not including a miners fee. I'll never do that again.  My question is, will they definitely be confirmed eventually?  What happens if they're not?  Here's the link to one of the transactions:

https://blockchain.info/tx/3254c99062b53b1988e84cccdf6c45b2d1fbf429f91c924d916e854797dd8819

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They will probably be confirmed eventually. But you don't have to wait. You can just form new transactions that spend the same outputs with the normal fee. The fact that there exists a conflicting unconfirmed transaction will have no effect on other transactions that attempt to spend the same outputs. You can be 100% sure they won't both go through, since an output can only be spent once. Unfortunately, depending on what tools you have, this may be difficult to accomplish.

Comment: You're using an inappropriate tool.

Comment: I sent the bitcoin from myself (online via blockchain.info My Wallet) to myself (offline via multibit wallet on my computer). If the transactions are never confirmed will the bitcoin eventually be restored in the wallet I sent them from so that I can try to resend them?